# touchstart touch end on asp.net button not reading event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, touchstart

Hi I am attempting to simulate a hover event in a mobile web application for mobile safari. 
Basically I have my asp.net button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" CssClass="btn-login" />
```

Now with javasrcipt I have to function that reads the touch start and touch end events:

```
    $('#coreContent_mainContent_Login_btnLogin').bind('touchstart touchend', function (e)   {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-sign-up-hover');
});
```

I then have this CSS Class which is being toggled with **btn-sign-up**:

```
.btn-sign-up {
   background: url(/images/sign-in-sprites.png) no-repeat -100px 0px;
   float: right;
   height: 20px;
   width: 104px;
   border: none;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
 }

.btn-sign-up-hover {
   background: url(/images/sign-in-sprites.png) no-repeat -100px -30px;
 }
```

For some reason the class isnt changing...is my code wrong or do i have a bad logic?

Answer (score 0):

Two questions: Are you using the correct Selector? Did you try "Visual Event" to check that jQuery added the events to the button? Sometimes you can solve issues using live() instead of bind() ... give it a try